# Disable Echoing PTY / Pseudo Terminal in C / C++ Unix Set PTY to non-echoing

Tags: c, pty

I've created a PTY (Pseudo Terminal) which Accepts Input and prints the output in C / C++ on Unix:

Nearly Everything works properly, nearly every command. But if I spawn a new shell, every command I type gets printed to the screen a second time before the output. Is there anyway how to disable this echoing ?
That would be the Error:

```
bash-3.2$ python3
Python 3.7.3 (default, Feb 30 2100, 24:00:00)
Type"help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.    
>>> import stackoverflow //for example
import stackoverflow 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'stackoverflow'
>>>
```

I know that this type of question has been asked several times, I just didn't manage to implement this function ;(

Here's the code so far:

```
int InteractiveShell() {
int fdm, fds;
int rc;
char buffer[TOK_BUFSIZE];

fdm = posix_openpt(O_RDWR);
rc = grantpt(fdm);

rc = unlockpt(fdm);
fds = open(ptsname(fdm), O_RDWR);     // Open the slave side ot the PTY

if (fork()) {     // Create the child process
    fd_set fd_in;

    // Parent Process
    close(fds); // Close the slave side of the PTY

    printf("[+] Setup Succeeded\n");
    while (1) {
        FD_ZERO(&fd_in); // Wait for data from standard input and master side of PTY
        FD_SET(0, &fd_in);
        FD_SET(fdm, &fd_in);

        rc = select(fdm + 1, &fd_in, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        switch(rc) {
          case -1: fprintf(stderr, "[-] Error %d on select()\n[-] Exiting\n", errno);
                    exit(1);

          default:{
            if (FD_ISSET(0, &fd_in)) {  // If data on standard input
                memset(&buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
                rc = (int) read(0, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
                if (rc > 0){
                    write(fdm, buffer, rc); // Send data on the master side of PTY
                } else {
                if (rc < 0) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Error %d on read standard input\n", errno);
                    exit(1);
                }
              }
            }
            if (FD_ISSET(fdm, &fd_in)) { // If data on master side of PTY
                memset(&buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
                rc = (int) read(fdm, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
                if (rc > 0) {
                    write(1, buffer, rc);
                } else {
                    if (rc < 0) {
                        fprintf(stderr, "Error %d on read master PTY\n", errno);
                        exit(1);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } // End switch
    } // End while
} else {    // CHILD
    struct termios slave_orig_term_settings; // Saved terminal settings
    struct termios new_term_settings; // Current terminal settings

      close(fdm); // Close the master side of the PTY

      rc = tcgetattr(fds, &slave_orig_term_settings);

      // Set RAW mode on slave side of PTY
      new_term_settings = slave_orig_term_settings;
      cfmakeraw (&new_term_settings);
      tcsetattr (fds, TCSANOW, &new_term_settings);

      close(0); // Close standard input (current terminal)
      close(1); // Close standard output (current terminal)
      close(2); // Close standard error (current terminal)

      dup(fds); // PTY becomes standard input (0)
      dup(fds); // PTY becomes standard output (1)
      dup(fds); // PTY becomes standard error (2)

      // Now the original file descriptor is useless
      close(fds);
      setsid();       // Make the current process a new session leader
      ioctl(0, TIOCSCTTY, 1);

      // Execution of the program
      {rc = execlp("/bin/bash", "-i", (char *) NULL);}
      return 1;
    }
    //return 0;
```

Any Ideas, suggestions, websites, ... ?
Thanks for your help,
Regards, from Brooks ♟

Comment: `C` or `C++` - 2 distinct languages - I do not see anything that would indicate `C++`, removing tag.

Comment: Do you have an 'echo' setting that you can switch off in your terminal setup menu?

Comment: @ryyker Hey, that's what I'm trying to do: I try to disable the echo function

Comment: Can you redirect content from spawned python to dev/nul ?  (`command >/dev/null`)

Comment: @ryyker That's not really what I'm trying to achieve, but thanks for your support

Comment: Generally you could change the code to detect any errors being returned. The code is incomplete also, so it does not really help to find out what's going wrong.

Comment: @U.Windl Would you like to have a look at the whole source code

Comment: @PrivateAccountOfBrooks See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example; it's not for *me*; it's for the community to help.